# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS freeze after login

Tags: 16.04, login, freeze

So I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my old laptop, and everything went fine. I installed Eclipse and everything was fine. After a couple of days i wanted to try out Ubuntu and everything was normal during boot. When the login screen came up and I entered my password to enter desktop, nothing happens. All I can see is the cursor (which I can move) and the wallpaper.
I can enter terminal through ctrl+shift + f1. I've tried a couple of things in commands about Nvidia drivers and stuff like that I've read on other websites but nothing has helped.

I could reinstall Ubuntu I don't have anything important on it, but if there is a command to fix this problem it would be great.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I think I have the same problem as you. In the terminal (ctrl-alt-F1), please run `uname -a` and `lspci | grep -i vga` and [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/856842/edit) your post with the output of each. It would also help if you posted any details you know about the make/model of your laptop and your GPU.

Comment: The title and body of your question say Ubuntu but the tags say "Xubuntu". Which one is it? More precisely we need to know which window manager you're using (e. g. Unity or Xfce). If you don't know, that's fine because that means you're probably using the default of your Ubuntu-flavoured distribution – we'll still need to know which one that is, hence my first question.

Comment: Oh sorry! Its suppose tonsay ubuntu i dont know where the x cane from. I dont know what window manager im using.. haha.

Comment: Uname -a: 4.4.0-31-generic #50-ubuntu SMP Wed jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/LINUX. Lspci | grep -i vga: VGA compatiblr coktroller: intel corporation 2nd generation core processor family integrated graphics controller (rev 9)